# Named return types for factory functions?

Tags: typescript

I can currently use interfaces and named types to describe the return value from a factory function

```
interface Thing {
    thing: string
}

const create = (): Thing => ({
    thing: 'sdf'
})
```

Without naming the return type, TypeScript infers the type from the return value - however the type is unnamed and chaos to read in my editor.

Is it possible to name the return type in a factory function?

I'm imagining something like

```
const create = () => ({
    thing: 'sdf'
} as Thing)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can describe type of `create` variable as a function that returns `Thing`:

```
const create: () => Thing = () => ({
    thing: 'sdf'
});
```

Comment: Perhaps my description wasn't clear but I want to declare the type name inline. This requires me to define `Thing` previously

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot declare `Thing` to use it later as `Thing` interface inside function declaration. You can show that func returns 'something that has thing prop': 
const create: () => {
    thing: string;
} = ...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it would be nice to do something like this:

```js
function foo() { // ❌
    interface Foo {x: number, y: number}
    return {x: 4, y: 5} as Foo
}
```

Or this:

```js
function foo(): Foo { // ❌
    interface Foo {x: number, y: number}
    return {x: 4, y: 5}
}
```

because it would allow you to name your return type without cluttering the module-level types. However, both give a compile-time error:

```
Return type of exported function has or is using private name 'Foo'.
```

Lastly, this doesn't parse at all:

```js
// ❌
function foo(): (interface Foo {x: number, y: number}) {
    return {x: 4, y: 5}
}
```

So you're stuck doing it at the module level. Note that the type does not need to be exported though.

```js
interface Foo {x: number, y: number}
export function foo(): Foo { // perfectly fine
    return {x: 4, y: 5}
}
```